# Why is `DeclarePairedDelimiter` so complicated?

Tags: mathtools, delimiters

Currently I use the following to type singleton sets:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\singleton}[2][]{\mathopen{#1\{}#2\mathclose{#1\}}}

\begin{document}
$\singleton x$, but $\singleton[\big]{(x, y)}$
\end{document}
```

I recently noticed that `mathtools` provides `DeclarePairedDelimiter` with the exact same interface, but with a somewhat weird implementation.

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter:
macro:#1#2#3->\@ifdefinable {#1}{\MT_delim_default_inner_wrappers:n {#1}\@namedef {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_star:}##1{\@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_star_wrapper:nnn}{\left #2}{##1}{\right #3}}\@xp \@xp \@xp \newcommand \@xp \csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_nostar:\endcsname [2][\\@gobble]{\def \@tempa {\\@gobble}\def \@tempb {##1}\ifx \@tempa \@tempb \@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_nostarnonscaled_wrapper:nnn}{#2}{##2}{#3}\else \MT_etb_ifblank:nnn {##1}{\@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_nostarnonscaled_wrapper:nnn}{#2}{##2}{#3}}{\@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_nostarscaled_wrapper:nnn}{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1l}#2}{##2}{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1r}#3}}\fi }\DeclareRobustCommand {#1}{\@ifstar {\@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_star:}}{\@nameuse {MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1_nostar:}}}}
```

(This is given by running `latexdef -p mathtools DeclarePairedDelimiter` in a shell.)

I would rather not import a package I don't understand the behavior of, if not necessary.
Is there any reason to use `mathtools` rather than my custom implementation? May the latter cause bugs or unexpected outputs?

Comment: most of the complication for declarepaireddelimiter is for the case you don't support at all getting better spacing with the arbitrary size variant using `\left` and `\right`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: but don't look at `latexdef -p mathtools DeclarePairedDelimiter` to understand the code look in `mathtools.dtx` where it is laid out on multiple lines with copious line by line documentation.

Comment: a command defined by declarepaired delimiter has a * form where the delimiter grows to be as large as the expression. You don't support that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh okay it makes sense, this answers my question, thank you